# How can we prevent page refresh on click of back button in angular 8?

Tags: angular

GoBack()`
 Window.history.back

Using GoBack() when I will navigate to previous page, but I want to prevent page reload at that time

How its possible, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#back) service. Inject Location service in constructor then call **back** method on injected service like this:

**component.ts:**

```
     constructor(private locationService: Location) {}

     goBack() {
      this.locationService.back();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the Router into your app.component and set its canceledNavigationResolution property to 'computed'.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [RouterModule],
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
   constructor(router: Router) {
      router.canceledNavigationResolution = 'computed';
   }
}
```